# How to use Google Identity Services JS SDK for authorization?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the authorization through google Auth and Javascript SDK following the example given by [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#authorization_code_flow_examples):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var client;
      function initClient() {
        client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
          client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
          ux_mode: 'popup',
          callback: (response) => {
            var code_receiver_uri = 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE_ENDPOINT_URI',
            // Send auth code to your backend platform
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', code_receiver_uri, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.onload = function() {
              console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send('code=' + code);
            // After receipt, the code is exchanged for an access token and
            // refresh token, and the platform then updates this web app
            // running in user's browser with the requested calendar info.
          },
        });
      }
      function getAuthCode() {
        // Request authorization code and obtain user consent
          client.requestCode();
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="getAuthCode();">Load Your Calendar</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

However there are two things I don't get in this example:

- What is the AUTHORIZATION_CODE_ENDPOINT_URI
- What is the variable named 'code' sent in the callback function ? It is not assigned anywhere in this snippet

Initializing the client works fine, I get the pop up window with the required scope however I can not figure out how to make the second part work and it seems to be fairly new, so not much information about this is available.

Comment: Hi, @Bernardinho, do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

`YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE_ENDPOINT_URI` is where your identity is verified and where `code` is being sent to. See here for more information on [Authorization Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1).

As for `code`. It's not this:

```
xhr.send('code=' + code);
```

It's this:

```
xhr.send('code=' + response.code);
```

We receive `code` as a response. That's how we get the value. See this line here.

```
callback: (response)
```

`code` is a part of the Google OAuth 2.0 process. It refers to the Authorization Code that Google sends you once you have verified your identity. Once you have received your code you can exchange it for a token that can be used to access Google APIs.

Any time the token expires, the application using has to request a new one via the access code. This provides a degree of separation from you and your passwords to the Google APIs.

See here for more info on [Authorization codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1).

See here for more info on [Google using OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver).

See diagram below to see the full process.

[image: Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications.]

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case, for `YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE_ENDPOINT_URI` I set it to my web server/backend endpoint URI. Afterward, I will use that verified code to request the access token within my backend.